# Switch statement isnt working properly while I'm using getchar()?

Tags: c

I need to write a program that goes through a `for` loop 4 times, and gets the user input. It can either be `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`. Otherwise it will print out `invalid operator`. When I run this program and put in `+`, it outputs `f = 30` (which I want) but then it outputs invalid operator right under it without me even putting in another character. Then I enter `-` and it outputs `invalid operator` twice. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) 

void main() {
    char ch;
    int f, a = 10, b = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ch = getchar();
        switch (ch) {
        case '+': f = a + b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
            break;
        case '−': f = a - b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
            break;
        case '*': f = a * b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
            break;
        case '/': f = a / b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
            break;
        default: printf("invalid operator\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To begin with you might want to check what [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) *actually* returns for type. *And* handle possible errors.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that when you enter an operator, you enter the operator *and* press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and that <kbd>Enter</kbd> key adds a newline in the input buffer which you will read but not handle.

Answer (score -1):

```
fflush(stdin);
```

When you received a input from `ch=getchar()`, you input one character and press enter, newline character is added in the input buffer too.

Try to use `fflush(stdin)` or `while(getchar()!='\n');`

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behaviour. Don't do that. Ever.

Comment: If fflush(stdin) has undefined behavior then you can use one more getchar() to collect the new line `\n` character i.e. `ch=getchar(); getchar()` .